# Chromatic Number of $S_2$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, topological-graph-theory

What is the largest chromatic number of all the graphs $G$ that can be embedded on $S_2$ (the double torus)? To which graph is it associated?

Comment: As mentioned on a previous (recent) post of yours, Heawood's formula (from 1890!) says that if $G$ is embeddable on $S_\gamma$ (the surface of genus $\gamma$; of course, we require $\gamma \geq 0$), then $G$ has chromatic number at most $\lfloor \frac{7 + \sqrt{1 + 48\gamma}}{2} \rfloor$. With $\gamma$ = 2, this evaluates to 8. Hence all graphs of genus 2 have $\chi(G) \leq 8$. I think your previous post also had an example of such a graph.

Comment: But is K_8 the graph which has maximum chromatic number over all graphs that are embeddable on genus 2? @Paralyzed_by_Time? If yes, why so?

Comment: Compute $\chi(K_8)$ and re-read my previous comment. I'm far from an expert on this topic, so I don't know whether $K_8$ uniquely maximizes your problem, but I doubt it. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will chime in.

Comment: @Thanks for your help, I know that Heawood works what I’m looking for is a way to show that chi(S_2) <=8 without using Heawood

Comment: Although it looks scary, the only machinery used in Heawood's formula is a generalization of Euler's formula to higher genus and an average degree argument; I don't think you'll find any simpler argument for bounding the chromatic number on the double-torus. I wish you the best of luck, however.

Comment: There are many graphs with chromatic number 8 which are embeddable on the double torus. For example, you can take *any* planar graph $G$ and “combine” it with $K_8$ by identifying one edge in each graph (this operation is known as a clique-sum https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique-sum).

Comment: @KcH thanks so much for this comment. Do you have an idea how one may deduce that max(chi(G)) for G being a graph embeddable on the double-torus is simply equal to 8 without using Heawood's number?